# BMP180 Looping of data being retrieved for and ending point of my choice.

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

So I have my BMP180 working with my Raspberry Pi 2 B. I want to try to get multiple sets of data from the BMP180 for x amount of time to have past by; as well as having a few min delay between when the data is being read. As well as have it stopping period of my choice. I'm new to python and coding as a whole, so any help and pointers would be appreciated..

Comment: You should add some of what you have already done, showing your effort, and try creating a minimal working example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can be able to understand what you are looking for and help more properly.

Comment: print 'Temp = {0:0.2f} *C'.format(sensor.read_temperature())
print 'Pressure = {0:0.2f} Pa'.format(sensor.read_pressure())
print 'Altitude = {0:0.2f} m'.format(sensor.read_altitude())
print 'Sealevel Pressure = {0:0.2f}  kPa'.format(sensor.read_sealevel_pressure()*1/1000)  I believe it comes from this. https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_BMP085/Adafruit_BMP085.py     I also followed this https://learn.adafruit.com/using-the-bmp085-with-raspberry-pi/using-the-adafruit-bmp-python-library.

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I got it using a while loop.